# How to over come Session Expiry in Salesforce

Tags: jquerymobile

I developed one Sales force Mobile App it is working fine. In salesforce, Security Controls in Session Settings there is an option "Timeout value" where we can set the Session Timeout. If I set it as 15 min, in my Mobile App, it wont logoff if we are working on the App. If I dont interrupt the App for 15 minutes  it will get logoff. How to over come this, from my JQuery code instead of changing it in salesforce. Will it be possible to do so?

Comment: Are you using oAuth to authenticate to Salesforce? if so you need to ask salesforce for a refresh token. http://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what overcoming this would mean for you.

As Sven suggested, if you are using oAuth and have been issued a refresh token you can use your refresh token to get a new access token and reauthenticate the user for another 15 minutes.

If that is not an option, you can perform a simple action on behalf of the user after X minutes of inactivity.  For example, query for users with limit 0 or something similar.  The drawback to this approach is hibernation (which I assume locking a phone is just like) stops javascript execution, in which case the session would only remain active as long as the phone is unlocked.